# Issue with deploying to Master using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: deployment

Whenever a branch got merged onto master in git, bitbucket automatically pushed/deploys the changes into production. However, this process isn't working anymore as it seems Salesforce has changed something.

It works locally, but fails when executed on Pipelines. We don’t get any more details other than that it fails. It seems that something changed on the Salesforce side. Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: If you look at Deployment Status in Salesforce, do you see a failed deployment there?

Comment: Hi David, we don't see any message, no.

Comment: That strongly suggest the error is on the Pipelines side. I'd check for authentication issues first and any logs available through BitBucket.

Comment: Hi David, this is the error we're seeing:

Comment: Error: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/jsforce/lib/connection.js:1077:13
    at tryCallOne (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Comment: BUT! The very same username, password and security token, when used to run the same job from a local machine, work fine.

Comment: Rosie, could you please edit this information directly into your question? Thanks!